# Use Taylor's Theorem for to establish the inequality $x-\frac{x^{2}}{2}\le \log(1+x) \le x-\frac{x^{3}}{2(1+x)}$

Tags: inequality

My professor told me to use Taylor Theorem with remainder form to establish this in equality but I don't get how to use this theorem.
Need some help
Thank you

Comment: Is my edit to your title correct?

Comment: @mrnovice yeah, thanks...did u get my question? Any hint for solving this?

Comment: Yes, just provide me with some context first, do you understand what a Taylor's series is, and how to derive it?

Comment: Also if this equality is true, it can only hold if it's $x-x^{2} \leq log(1+x) \leq x - \frac{x^{3}}{2(1+x)}$

Comment: @mrnovice yeah, I'm completely  known to taylor series derivation but don't know how to apply remainder form to establish this inequality. Choosing f(x) = log(1+x)

Comment: @Rahul What do you think about my solution?

Comment: @Rahul: You *removed* the restriction $0 \le x \le 1$ from the question title. But actually the inequality is wrong for some $x > 1$ (as pointed out below) and also wrong for $x < 0$.

Comment: @MartinR The $0 \le x \le 1$ constraint was edited into the (title of the) question by someone *other* than the OP (per the edit history). Quoting from an earlier comment of mine: *note that I am not saying that the condition doesn't makes sense, but only that it was never mentioned by the OP to begin with*.

Comment: @dxiv: Yes I know and agree. I just wondered that OP himself removed the condition instead of confirming it and clarifying the question.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: Proof for the upper bound: $\displaystyle x-\log(1+x)=\int_0^t \frac{t}{1+t}dt>\frac1{1+x}\int_0^x tdt=\frac{x^2}{2(1+x)}$. $\forall x\ge0$. Moreover, $\displaystyle\frac{x^2}{2(1+x)}>\frac{x^3}{2(1+x)}$, $\forall x\in(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

$\ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-...$.

Thus, $\ln(1+x)\geq x-\frac{x^2}{2}$ and

$$\ln(1+x)\leq x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\frac{x^5}{5}-\frac{x^6}{6}+\frac{x^7}{7}-\frac{x^8}{8}+\frac{x^9}{9}\leq x-\frac{x^3}{2(1+x)},$$
where the last inequality it's
$$(1260-840x-210x^2+126x^3-84x^4+60x^5-45x^6+37x^7-280x^8)x^2\geq0,$$
which is obvious for $0\leq x\leq1$ because
\begin{align}
&1260-840x-210x^2+126x^3-84x^4+60x^5-45x^6+37x^7-280x^8 \\
=&840(1-x)+210(1-x^2)+210(1-x^8)+84x^3(1-x)+45x^5(1-x)+42x^3(1-x^5) \\
&+15x^5(1-x^3)+13x^7(1-x)+24x^7 \\
\geq&0.
\end{align}
Done!

Comment: @ Michael Rozenberg sorry for mistakes, I just made the corrections

Comment: I feel you should include a few more in-between steps in your answer

Comment: @mrnovice What is your question? I am ready to answer.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg `obvious for 0≤x≤1` Obviousness aside, but why $x \le 1$? OP's question makes no mention of range restrictions.

Comment: @dxiv  The topic-starter changed the given many times. The last version was with $0\leq x\leq1$ and I missed to edit it. I am sorry.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg The [edit history](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2160339/revisions) does not show the OP mentioning $0 \le x \le 1$ at any point. In fact, this condition only appears in *your* very latest edit of the title. (Note that I am not saying that the condition doesn't makes sense, but only that it was never mentioned by the OP to begin with.) Edits that materially *change* the question are generally frowned upon.

Comment: @dxiv I saw how  Rahul edited his post. Ask him.

Comment: Why is the last step true?

Comment: @Hans Because $840\geq840x$, $210\geq210x^2$, $84x^3\geq84x^4$, $45x^5\geq45x^6$, $37x^7\geq37x^8$ and $210+42x^3+15x^5-243x^8\geq0$.

Comment: Thank you! But could you please further explain the last inequality? From its plot, the root closest to $1$ is about $1.013$, which is very close to $1$, so I suppose the estimate should be very tight.

Comment: @Hans Because $210\geq210x^8$ and $33x^3\geq33x^8$.

Comment: Ah, yes. Very clever! And I have been obtuse. Would you mind writing it out in your answer of posterity so to speak --- even though it is too obvious for you? Thank you.

Comment: I am wondering where the upper bound comes from. Could it be a Pade approximant or a continued fraction approximation?

Answer (score 1):

$\ln(1+x) \le x-\cfrac{x^{3}}{2(1+x)}\;$ fails at $x=2$ for example, since $\ln(3) \gt 1 \gt \cfrac{2}{3} = 2 - \cfrac{2^3}{2\cdot 3}\,$.

Comment: The topic-starter changed the given many times. The last version was with $0\leq x\leq1$ and I missed to edit it. I am sorry.

Comment: To later readers, please note that the condition $0 \le x \le 1$ was inserted into the title *after* my answer was posted.

Comment: I saw how  Rahul edited his post. Ask him.